# Android: How to intercept HTTPURLConnection network calls?

Tags: android, networking, httpurlconnection, intercept

How can we intercept java.net.HttpURLConnection network requests? However, we can achieve interception using OKHTTPClient. Please help.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to modify request/response with `OkHttpClient` you can use interceptors. For example If you want to add a header to all requests, you can use the code below. Modifying other parts like body is similar.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();

                Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization",
                        Credentials.basic("aUsername", "aPassword"));

                Request newRequest = builder.build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();
```

Comment: Thanks. Question is how we can intercept HTTPURLConnection network calls?